Cannot create files from XSD schema with annox
I'm struggling with migration from JAXB 2 to latest version. I'm using an XSD file and an XJB file which contains annotation for the root element. But if I try to compile it, it ends up with an error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.0.8:generate (schema-v2) on project org.myproject.exporter: Execution schema-v2 of goal org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.0.8:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.0.8:generate: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.0.8
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb/jaxb-maven-plugin/4.0.8/jaxb-maven-plugin-4.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar
... a bunch of similiar error lines ...
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1

I don't want to use java.xml (but jakarta.xml instead), but I don't know where it is included. So, here is my XSD file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100"
    xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100"
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100"
    targetNamespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100"
    xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="3.0"
    xmlns:annox="urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:annox"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100" schemaLocation="FACTUR-X_EXTENDED_urn_un_unece_uncefact_data_standard_QualifiedDataType_100.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" schemaLocation="FACTUR-X_EXTENDED_urn_un_unece_uncefact_data_standard_ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity_100.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100" schemaLocation="FACTUR-X_EXTENDED_urn_un_unece_uncefact_data_standard_UnqualifiedDataType_100.xsd"/>
  <!-- definition slightly changed so that xjb could annotate it with XmlRootelement -->
  <xs:element name="CrossIndustryInvoice">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ExchangedDocumentContext" type="ram:ExchangedDocumentContextType"/>
          <xs:element name="ExchangedDocument" type="ram:ExchangedDocumentType"/>
          <xs:element name="SupplyChainTradeTransaction" type="ram:SupplyChainTradeTransactionType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

and this is the XJB file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:annox="urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:annox"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="900" enableJavaNamingConventions="true" underscoreBinding="asCharInWord" typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName">
        <!-- Use java.util.Calendar instead of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar for xs:dateTime -->
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                parseMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                printMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />
         
        <!-- Force all classes implements Serializable -->
        <jaxb:serializable uid="1" />
        
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
 
    <!-- Annotate the following classes with XmlRootElement -->
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="FACTUR-X_EXTENDED.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings><jaxb:package name="org.myproject.export.facturx.modelgen" /></jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='CrossIndustryInvoice']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="CrossIndustryInvoiceType"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

The pom file includes the following:
            <!-- generate schema file for entities
     generate JAXB classes for entities -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema-v2</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>3.0</specVersion>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <locale>en</locale>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema-v2</schemaDirectory>
                             <!-- xjb doesn't work :-( -->
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/schema-v2</bindingDirectory> 
                            <generateDirectory>src-gen/main/java</generateDirectory>
                            <encoding>${encoding}</encoding>
                            <generatePackage>org.myproject.export.facturx.modelgen</generatePackage>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
                                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                                <arg>-npa</arg>
                            </args>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jaxb2.basics.version}</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
                                  <artifactId>jaxb-plugin-annotate</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jaxb2.basics.version}</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>                                    
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jaxb2.basics.version}</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>1.11.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0.14</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb-fluent-api</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1.8</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-default-value</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

It seems that fluent-api and annotate aren't recognized anymore. With org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 v0.14.0 all things were generated successfully without any errors.
If you could give me a hint where I can start to fix it you're welcome :-) Thanks in advance,
Ralf
